# In MVC 4 I need to display two views in one view. I have tried to use Iframe but it keeps telling resource can not found 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe, razor

I have two view and i need to display both of them in one view or one page so i tried to use Iframe so i put the following code

```
<iframe src='@Url.Action("Views/Charts/ProjectBudgetActualVsEstimated", "ProjectBudgetActualVsEstimated")' width="100%"   height="1000" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but it keeps telling me that (resource can not found 404 ). the view only displays it's view and on the rest of the page it's giving (resource can not found 404 )

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Provide some code to have any chance of getting help.

Comment: This the code i was trying <iframe src='@Url.Action("ProjectBudgetActualVsEstimated", "ProjectBudgetActualVsEstimated")' width="100%"
    height="1000" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: Have you tried Partial Views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Resource cannot be found** states that either your `url` in `src` is incorrect or you do not have that particular action method in your
>   controller

Your `iframe src` seems to be fishy!!

`@Url.Action()` will have a overloaded method which takes 2 parameters and they are `actionname`, `controllerName` as one below:

```
public virtual string Action(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName
)
```

So you either need to opt for `@Url.Action` in `src` or just give relative path and I would like to provide both option samples for you.

Using `@Url.Action`, assuming `ProjectBudgetActualVsEstimated` is your `actionname`

```
<iframe src='@Url.Action("controllerName", "ProjectBudgetActualVsEstimated")' width="100%"   height="1000" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Using `relativepath`

```
<iframe src="/controllerName/ProjectBudgetActualVsEstimated" width="100%"   height="1000" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In both the cases the generated `url` will be `www.yourdomain.com/controllerName/ProjectBudgetActualVsEstimated`

**Note:** `controllerName` is what name you have given to your controller where your `ProjectBudgetActualVsEstimated` `ActionResult` has been written!

Now other solution!

If you want to display 2 `views` in your page just make use of `PartialViews` and render it in your page with various options available.

Here is **[one link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC)** on how to do it